Unsure about assumptions of linear model with time series variables, spurious regression and periodic patterns
Background
I'm learning about time series in context of linear regression. The goal of this question is to understand how seasonality of either X or Y can affect the model.
Linear model assumptions

$Y \in R^t$ is a linear combination of $X_1, ... X_n \in R^t$ with added noise term, i.e.
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + ... + \beta_n X_n + \epsilon.$$

$\epsilon \sim N_t(0, I\sigma^2)$ (homoscedasticity, multivariate normality and lack of autocorrelation of residuals)

lack of multicollinearity of observations


What I don't understand

What happens if X/Y/both are non-stationary? Are there any risks related to that other than "spurious regression"?
As far as I understand, spurious regression can happen when dependent variable and one of independent variables have the same non-stationary pattern (cointegration), for instance they both have positive trend or the same seasonal fluctiations pattern. If so, do we need to care about non-stationarity of $X$, in case we know that $Y$ is stationary?
What about periodic patterns which are technically stationary (cyclic patterns)?


Where did you find this list of assumptions?

@RichardHardy I've created this list based on information from several webpages combined with my own knowledge. Is anything wrong with this list?

E.g. point 3: I do not think zero correlation and lack of multicollinearity are the same thing.

@RichardHardy thank you, you're right, I removed zero correlation part

What about the zero autocorrelation of Xs? Is that a must?

@RichardHardy I believe that in general, there is an assumption that observations in each vector $X_i$ are independent, which implies zero correlation. I am aware that zero correlation doesn't imply independence - but I think that in practice zero correlation is the only thing we care about. For example this Medium article states that "regression will produce inaccurate standard errors with correlated data". I don't have enough time to perform experiments myself right now but it sound correct

The assumption of independence is on the $\epsilon$, not $X$. You can easily have equal $X$ values when $X$ is categorical with few categories, e.g. $X$ is a dummy variable indicating sex and the model is a regression of wage on sex.

@RichardHardy You're right - there is no such assumption about X, I removed it from the list. On the other hand, main assumptions of the linear model don't include stationarity - yet still it can cause problems. Same for outliers. And maybe it's the same for autocorrelated regressors (i.e. they can cause problems in specific cases) and that's why some resources mention that. I will definitely spend more time researching this topic, I've already found related questions on Stack and saved them for later. Thank you.

For your first and third question, why not try it and see? Here is a very crude shot at it with R; it would be easy to play with this:
set.seed(1234)

#Generate random varaibles
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

#Add cyclic noise
xcyl <- x + rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 250)
ycyl <- y + rep(c(1,-1,1, -1), 250) #different cycle

m1 <- lm(ycyl~xcyl)
summary(m1)

Which yields:
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.47306    0.08507   5.561 3.45e-08 ***
xcyl        -0.18539    0.02944  -6.297 4.55e-10 ***

For your second question: No, they can have different patterns and still be spurious. For one thing, they can be opposite. You could, e.g., regress the Dow Jones Average on deaths from polio and find a strong negative relationship.
